# Why does Spark shuffle store intermediate data on disk?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

Why does spark store intermediate data on disk during shuffle?  I am trying to understand why it cannot store in memory.  What are the challenges to write to memory?

Is some work being done to write it to Memory?

Comment: You can set "spark.shuffle.spill" to false to write intermediate data to memory.

Comment: Why this is not a default option?

Answer (score 5):

Spark stores intermediate data on disk from a shuffle operation as part of its "under-the-hood" optimization.  When spark has to recompute a portion of a RDD graph, it may be able to truncate the lineage of a RDD graph if the RDD is already there as a side effect of an earlier shuffle.  This can happen even if the RDD is not cached or explicitly persisted.

The source of this answer is the O'Reilly book Learning Spark by Karau, Konwinski, Wendell & Zaharia. Chapter 8: Tuning and Debugging Spark. Section: Components of Execution: Jobs, Tasks, and Stages.